# issue with HTML and PHP language

Tags: php, html

I have issue with my login page, when I add my code don't display any action.

please see the below

Index.html

```
  <form  >

      <fieldset style="width:355;">

          <legend></legend>

          <div id="Form">
          <br><p><b> Log in</b></p>

          <br>

                     </div>

          <div class="col1 pad_left1">

              <form name="logForm" onsubmit="return log()" action="log_exe.php" method="POST" >

                 &nbsp; <label style="font-size:100%;" >Email:</label> </br>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="email1" placeholder="user@hotmail.com" id="email1" style="border:1px solid black; width:80%;" /> <b style="color:red;">*</b> </br><br>

                  &nbsp; <label style="font-size:100%;" > password:</label> </br>
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Password" id="pass1" style="border:1px solid black; width:80%;" /> <b style="color:red;">*</b>
                  <b style="display:none; color:red;" id="hide1">Sorry !! Wrong username or password</b>
                  </br>
                  <br>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size:120%;width:40%;padding:1%" type="submit" value="Log in" name="login" /></br><br>

              </form>
          </div>


      </fieldset>
  </form>
```

log_exe.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_PASSWORD = '';
$DB_DATABASE = 'la';

$con=mysql_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$con)
{
    die('Failed to connect to server: '.mysql_error());
}

$db=mysql_select_db($DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db)
{
    die("Unable to select database");
}

$email =$_POST['email1'];
$pass =$_POST['pass1'];

$qry="SELECT Email FROM user WHERE Email='".$email."' AND Password='".$pass."';";
$qry2="SELECT email FROM Admin WHERE email='".$email."' AND password='".$pass."';";

$result=mysql_query($qry);
$result2=mysql_query($qry2);


if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
{
    $admin = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $_SESSION['Email'] = $admin['Email'];

    header("location: schedule.php?Email=".$admin['Email']);
    exit();
}


if(mysql_num_rows($result2) == 1)
{
    $admin = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);

    $_SESSION['Email'] = $admin['Email'];

    header("location: controlpanel.php?Email=".$admin['Email']);
    exit();
}

else
{
    die ("<script> window.confirm(\"Sorry !! Wrong username or password !!\");</script> <a href='index.html#!/page_Schedule'>Click here</a> to return to login page");
}

?>
```

My problem is my website don't gave me response , when I enter email and pass the page is refresh to other page and the link became like this

http://localhost/myfolder/index.html?email1=user%40hotmail.com&pass1=123&login=Log+in#.php

Thank you for your response

Comment: when this happen. while submitting your form or textbox onblur event?

Comment: Is there any kind of error? Check your php_error_log or add `error_reporting(E_ALL);    ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beggining of you file and show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove these `<form  > </form>`  tag and you can see your action. your code will be like below

```
<fieldset style="width:355;">

          <legend></legend>

          <div id="Form">
          <br><p><b> Log in</b></p>

          <br>

                     </div>

          <div class="col1 pad_left1">

              <form name="logForm" onsubmit="return log()" action="log_exe.php" method="POST" >

                 &nbsp; <label style="font-size:100%;" >Email:</label> </br>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="email1" placeholder="user@hotmail.com" id="email1" style="border:1px solid black; width:80%;" /> <b style="color:red;">*</b> </br><br>

                  &nbsp; <label style="font-size:100%;" > password:</label> </br>
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Password" id="pass1" style="border:1px solid black; width:80%;" /> <b style="color:red;">*</b>
                  <b style="display:none; color:red;" id="hide1">Sorry !! Wrong username or password</b>
                  </br>
                  <br>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size:120%;width:40%;padding:1%" type="submit" value="Log in" name="login" /></br><br>

              </form>
          </div>


      </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the unwanted form from your index.html. ie modify the code like the following:

```
<fieldset style="width:355;">

          <legend></legend>

          <div id="Form">
          <br><p><b> Log in</b></p>

          <br>

                     </div>

          <div class="col1 pad_left1">

              <form name="logForm" onsubmit="return log()" action="log_exe.php" method="POST" >

                 &nbsp; <label style="font-size:100%;" >Email:</label> </br>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="email1" placeholder="user@hotmail.com" id="email1" style="border:1px solid black; width:80%;" /> <b style="color:red;">*</b> </br><br>

                  &nbsp; <label style="font-size:100%;" > password:</label> </br>
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Password" id="pass1" style="border:1px solid black; width:80%;" /> <b style="color:red;">*</b>
                  <b style="display:none; color:red;" id="hide1">Sorry !! Wrong username or password</b>
                  </br>
                  <br>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size:120%;width:40%;padding:1%" type="submit" value="Log in" name="login" /></br><br>

              </form>
          </div>


      </fieldset>
```

Comment: display other page but with this message                                                   Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.